# Visual studio the only IDE for C programming?

Tags: c, ide

I'm looking for an IDE with compiler to work on C language on Windows 7. It must be the c99 ANSI standard(not quite sure what this means).

I've been looking through several questions on this site and it appears Visual Studio is the only IDE available out there. Can anyone confirm/deny this?

I've been using the MinGW compilers to compile .c files and it seemed to work just fine. It would just be awesome to have an eclipse/netbeans layout for C programming too but I guess that doesn't exist.

Thanks for your time

Comment: You do know that both Eclipse and NetBeans, as well as many other IDEs, exists for Windows? (See e.g. [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_integrated_development_environments#C.2FC.2B.2B)) You also know that Visual Basic is a *language*, and not to be confused with the Visual Studio IDE.

Comment: code::blocks, geany.. these are open source also.

Comment: What's wrong with Visual Studio ?

Comment: @MichaelWalz, `It must be the c99 ANSI standard`

Comment: @Alter Mann: ok, I was not aware that even the lates VS is not c99 compliant.

Comment: @Dipto I didn't know Eclipse worked for C. We used eclipse when we worked with java. I'm going to look into it now.

Comment: @John Eclipse works with pretty much every language you want, as it has a lot of plugins and is quite customizable

Comment: QtCreator is a cross-platform IDE supporting C and C++. A version bundled with MinGW can also be downloaded from the web site.

Comment: I will recommend code::blocks with MinGW.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both [Netbeans](https://netbeans.org/features/cpp/) and [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/downloads/moreinfo/c.php) support C development.
They just don't contain a compiler (or debugger) in their installation packages
so they both require installation of a compiler (mainly cygwin or mingw -that you already use- )

Setup instructions:

```
netbeans.org/community/releases/74/cpp-setup-instructions.html
help.eclipse.org/help33/index.jsp?topic=/org.eclipse.cdt.doc.user/concepts/cdt_c_before_you_begin.htm
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use Dev-C++ 
orwell devc++

Comment: Please don't recommend dev-c++